# How to I downgrade laravel 8 project to laravel 7 step by step?

Tags: laravel

I want to downgrade laravel 8 project to laravel 7

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4.1",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5|dev-develop",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: that's why you should have version control system !! Possible solution, create a new project on v7. Copy all the codes and dependencies and make necessary changes that might have changed from v7 to v8.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7.x/composer.json for common versions, use your custom packages homepages to get their version number for L7. And maybe Laravel's [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade) will help

Comment: The real question is why ? i'm sure there is a better solution to your problem than downgrading laravel

Comment: why, why, why ......

Answer (score 0):

**Update the following dependencies in your composer.json file:**

- laravel/framework to ^7.0
- nunomaduro/collision to ^4.1
- phpunit/phpunit to ^8.5
- laravel/tinker to ^2.0
- facade/ignition to ^2.0

laravel ui should be version 2

```
composer require laravel/ui "^2.0"
```

Next, in your composer.json file, add `classmap` block from the `autoload` section and add the new namespaced class directory mappings:

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
    "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
}
},
```

and in the `AppServiceProvider` in the `boot` method add the following line

```
Paginator::useBootstrap();
```

I hope it was useful !